# How to look for edge match in graph database

Tags: java, spring, orientdb

I study the OrientDB solution and I have no idea how can I solve the following problem. 
I have some graph data (some routes in my country) and I would like to find every routes which has common edges with my input query. 
I use java for the solution.

Here is my example: There is a A-> B -> C -> D, A-> C, B-> C-> D lines in the database and I have a B -> C edge. I would like to get only that lines where the B -> C edge is existing so the A-> B -> C -> D and the B-> C-> D only.

Do you have any idea how can I do it? I guess the OrientDB should know this feature without any custom code.

Thanks in advance: Gábor

Comment: are those routes stored as strings?

Comment: I don't know how the OrientDB will store the routes. The original format of the routes are getting from simple json file(s). From these files I will create java pojo-s, and from the pojo I would like to store in DB.

Comment: if those were string, you could make contains("B->C"), that's why i asked